# Basis for dual in infinite dimensional vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I know to make it for $V$ finite dimensional. Give me a hint for infinite dimensional case.

Let $V$ be a vector space with basis $\{v_{i} \}_{i \in I}$. For each $i \in I$, let $f_i \in V^{\ast}$ defined by $f_i (v_i ) = 1$ and $f_i (v_j ) = 0$ if $j\neq i$.

a) Show that $\{f_i  \}_{i\in I } $ is linearly independent.

b) Show that $\{f_i \}_{i\in I } $ generates $V^{\ast}$ if only if $I$ is finite.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it is not the $f_i(v_i)$ but only the $f_i$ which should be independent and generators ?

Comment: Hint .If  $S$ is a finite non-empty subset of $ I$ and $g=\sum_{i\in S}a_if_i$, suppose $g=0$. What is $g(v_i)$ for $i\in S$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For linear independence: if $\sum_{i \in J} c_i \cdot f_i = 0$ in $V^{\ast}$, where $J \subset I$ is finite, evaluate the sum at $v_j$, for $j \in J$ and see what happens.

If $I$ is infinite, you have to find a functional on $V$ that is not a finite linear combination of any of the $f_i$'s. To this end, split $I$ into two infinite disjoint subsets $J$ and $K$. Then define $f(v_i) = 1$ if $i \in J$ and $f(v_i) = 0$ if $i \in K$, and extend linearly. Show that $f$ works.