# questions about advanced Linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, duality-theorems

I have some questions about advanced linear algebra. Let $V$ be a vector space and $V^*$ be the dual space.

1. Why is $V=V^*$ called non-natural, 
   and  $V=V^{**}$   called natural?
2. $V$ is a vector space with dimension $\dim V=\infty$. Give an example where $V$ is not equal to $V*$ and $V$ is not equal to $V**$ ?
3. If $\langle .,.\rangle$ is a non-degenerate scalar product on $V$, and
   $$\varphi: V \to V^{*}: v \mapsto L_v(w) = \langle w,v \rangle$$
   is not an isomorphism. Give an example.

Comment: I prefer canonic rather than natural. Canonic or natural in linear algebra means, that we can find an isomorphism between two spaces which does not depend on a choice of a basis in the two spaces. It is well known, that the double dual space is isomorphic to the underlying space independently on a choice of an explicit basis.

Comment: Relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1519457/basis-for-dual-in-infinite-dimensional-vector-space, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/13322/slick-proof-a-vector-space-has-the-same-dimension-as-its-dual-if-and-only-if-i.

Comment: In [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1900179/the-isomorphism-of-a-linear-space-with-its-dual-and-double-dual/1900519#1900519), I provide an explanation of why the isomorphism $V \to V^{**}$ is natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $V\ne V^*$ and $V\ne V^{**}$ **always**, but in finite dimension $V\cong V^*$ and $V\cong V^{**}$ trivially because all have the same dimension. But in the second case there is a **natural** (definable independently of basis) isomorphism, namely:
$$v\longmapsto e_v,\qquad e_v(f) = f(v),\qquad v\in V, f\in V^*.$$
Now, check what happens when $\dim V = \infty$. For example, $V = \Bbb R\oplus\Bbb R\oplus\cdots =$ space of eventually zero real sequences.

Comment: can you explain more ?

Comment: @ShabeebAl-alawi, about what, specifically?

Comment: The example ?

I would like to find en example for each case :
V  is not equal to V∗
V  is not equal to V∗∗ 

and an example for the third question?